# Trouble with nav bar repositioning

Tags: html, css, navigation, position, navbar

I was creating my website and noticed that my navbar with dropdown lists was positioned a lot lower than I wanted. I promptly tried to use a few different methods, like margins and paddings, position: fixed and position: absolute and setting the distance from the top, but that just pretty much removed my dropdown lists. I am curious to find out why that happened and what I can do to fix my code.

```css
h1 {
 font-size: 54px;
 font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
 margin: 10px;
 color: white;
}
body {
 background: url("flowers.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
}


.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
 background-color: rgba(249, 197, 249, 0.5);
 width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: rgb(249, 197, 249);
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(249, 197, 249);
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Japan.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kalam" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet"> 
<title>
Japan
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Japan: Land of the Rising Sun</h1>
<div style="margin-top: 110px"class="navbar">
  <a href="">Intro</a>
  <a href="">WEIRD Facts</a>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Nature
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="Fauna.htm">Fauna</a>
<a href="Flora.htm">Flora</a>
<a href="Geography.htm">Geography</a>
</div>
</div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Culture
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="Cuisine.html">Cuisine</a>
      <a href="Clothing.html">Clothing</a>
      <a href="Traditions.html">Traditions</a>
   <a href="Sports.html">Sports</a>
   <a href="Holidays.html">Holidays</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where you want navbar with dropdown lists position.

Answer (score 0):

you have spacing because of unwanted margin and `h1` tag  above `navbar`

so you need to removed margin from class `navbar` and move `h1` below `navbar`

see demo below

```css
h1 {
 font-size: 54px;
 font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
 margin: 10px;
 color: #333;
}
body {
 background: url("flowers.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
margin: 0;
}


.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
 background-color: rgba(249, 197, 249, 0.5);
 width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: rgb(249, 197, 249);
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(249, 197, 249);
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Japan.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kalam" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet"> 
<title>
Japan
</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Japan: Land of the Rising Sun</h1>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="">Intro</a>
  <a href="">WEIRD Facts</a>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Nature
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="Fauna.htm">Fauna</a>
<a href="Flora.htm">Flora</a>
<a href="Geography.htm">Geography</a>
</div>
</div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Culture
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="Cuisine.html">Cuisine</a>
      <a href="Clothing.html">Clothing</a>
      <a href="Traditions.html">Traditions</a>
   <a href="Sports.html">Sports</a>
   <a href="Holidays.html">Holidays</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for that answer. But on previous websites I have made the h1 tag above the nav bar and it seemed to work. I really don't want to make my h1 tag underneath the navbar because of aesthetic. However, if there are no other options, then I will do that.

Comment: visually where you want your heading to display, below navbar or above navbar ?

Comment: Above the navbar

Comment: previously it was like that only but text is having white color so you thought it as a huge gap above navbar

Comment: Wow! you did it! Thanks for helping!

Comment: glad I could help, If it fixed your problem then you can marked this as answer by clicking on tick on left side of this answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a normalize.css or reset.css that's give you a point to start on every project, with the same styles in every browser:

https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 0):

you may want to look into bootstrap.
with bootstrap you can easily create a beautiful and clean webpage.

[bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/)

I think the HTML code below is what you want to do. (minus your styling off course)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <style>
    .bd-placeholder-img {
      font-size: 1.125rem;
      text-anchor: middle;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
        font-size: 3.5rem;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <title>
    Japan
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Intro<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">WEIRD Facts<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Nature</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Fauna.htm">Fauna</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Flora.htm">Flora</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Geography.htm">Geography</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Culture</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Cuisine.html">Cuisine</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Clothing.html">Clothing</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Traditions.html">Traditions</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Sports.html">Sports</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Holidays.html">Holidays</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main role="main">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="d-flex align-items-stretch align-self-stretch">Japan: Land of the Rising Sun</h1>
        <p>


          Mauris egestas pretium mollis. Sed auctor, massa id feugiat bibendum, magna ante cursus erat, sit amet tristique neque lorem ac lacus. Sed sit amet eros et erat sagittis aliquam eget non tortor. In facilisis, ligula dictum feugiat volutpat, massa neque
          suscipit magna, eu blandit nulla leo sed nibh. In fermentum sem lacus, sit amet vulputate ex auctor sit amet. Nulla varius libero sit amet est luctus eleifend. Duis eu nibh et mi porta tempus et a libero. Maecenas dolor risus, ultricies sit
          amet eleifend a, venenatis et ipsum. Aenean purus tellus, pulvinar auctor lectus eu, sodales luctus elit. Suspendisse pharetra mattis justo, id bibendum sem aliquet a. Integer suscipit eu elit tincidunt tempor. Sed placerat rhoncus nisl, eget
          semper lectus feugiat eu. Vivamus eget felis sed est elementum ullamcorper quis sit amet orci. Praesent vel diam vel velit tempor varius. Nunc et mi eget purus egestas congue quis a tellus. Sed interdum sapien lectus, sed tincidunt dolor blandit
          a. Fusce lobortis tempus libero sed vestibulum. Donec fringilla lectus nisi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur a ex ut felis dictum commodo. Integer consectetur elit vitae mattis
          volutpat. Cras tincidunt ex id justo sodales commodo. Maecenas id accumsan orci. Morbi id nibh sit amet nibh rutrum elementum sed ac sem. Integer efficitur ac diam ac tempus. Sed in venenatis metus. Aliquam consectetur purus id enim dictum,
          sed tempor est iaculis. Suspendisse maximus libero id erat dictum blandit. Duis tincidunt maximus tortor, aliquet posuere quam faucibus vitae.
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```